# Is it best practice to always check the return value of PDOStatement::execute?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a `Permission` class with a method similar to the following.

```
public function AddComponentToAccount($component_id,$account_id)
{       
    $sql = "INSERT INTO component_permissions
            (account_id,component_id)
            VALUES
            (:account_id,:component_id)";

    $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindValue(':acount_id',$account_id);
    $q->bindValue(':component_name',$component_id);
    $q->execute();
}
```

My question is - should the final line really be `return $q->execute();`? Of the two following, which is better? Or is this subjective?

```
if(!$Permission->AddComponentToAccount($component_id,$account_id)){
    ...
}
```

-

```
try {
    $Permission->AddComponentToAccount($component_id,$account_id)
} catch(Exception $e) {
    HandleError($e);
}
```

I already know that the variables being passed into `AddComponentToAccount` are good. Exceptions could be a composite PK violation, or the fact that the DB is down.

Comment: imho don't let the factory do the exception handling. It's not his task. It's task is to fetch/process data from and to the database. Handle exceptions at one central place. This also useful when u distribute your code to others, so they can decide for themself what to do with the exceptions thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the PDO Error Handling method.

- If you are using `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, then you need a try...catch block
- If you are using `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` or `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` you only need to manage error code(s)

Now considering where to manage the error, I prefer to let exceptions bubble up in the caller code, in this way you can manage your behavior based on the caller (that is what exception are made for).

Addressing your question, if you are using `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` you don't need to manage **both** the return code and the exception itself.